# Conditional variable definition in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

i want to change the variable value based on a condition
so i tried the following:

```
<h:head>

    <ui:param name="userCase" value="Insert" />

    <ui:fragment rendered="#{employee.employeesBulkInsert==false}">
       <ui:param name="userCase" value="Update" />
    </ui:fragment>

       <title>#{userCase} Employee </title>

</h:head>
```

but it doesn't work in the update case, it shows an empty string, any ideas why ?

i know that there are other solutions like defining the variable in the backing bean, or make the conditional ui fragment on the title tag directly, but i want to know why the above is not working, please advise, thanks.

Comment: It's very good practice to say what behaviour you are experiencing (an error?  What's the message?  Not the output you expect?  What you were expecting?), not just "doesn't work".

Comment: sure, i will update the question :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `<ui:fragment>` is a render-time tag while the `<ui:param>` is a tag handler (tag handlers are easily recognizeable by the absence of the `rendered` attribute). So when the view get built, the `<ui:param>` is set, regardless of the outcome of `<ui:fragment>`. The `rendered` attribute of `<ui:fragment>` is only evaluated when the already-built view is to be rendered.

You want to make the condition using a tag handler instead, such as JSTL `<c:if>`.

```
<ui:param name="userCase" value="Insert" />

<c:if test="#{not employee.employeesBulkInsert}">
    <ui:param name="userCase" value="Update" />
</c:if>
```

*(note that I removed the unnecessary boolean `==false` comparison)*

Answer (score 2):

Try using JSTL instead:

```
<c:set var="userCase" value="Insert" />
<c:if test="#{employee.employeesBulkInsert}">
    <c:set var="userCase" value="Update" />
</c:if>
```

Tutorial here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211/index.html