# Using h:selectBooleanCheckbox with c:if to obtain row value of a <rich:datatable> - JSF

Tags: jsf

I'm using a `<rich:datatable>` to show the content of a `List<Map<String, String>`

In the code below, **spotlightPtBindings** is the `List<Map<String, String>` and **spotlightbinding** represents each `Map<String, String>`. In the first column, I'm showing one **selectBooleanCheckBox** for eah row. When a **selectBooleanCheckBox** is checked, I'd like to send the value of the `Map<String, String>` corresponding to the key "URI" as a parameter to the method: **inserirBean.onSelectedCheckBox(uri)**, and that's why I put this value in a **ui:param** of name: **uri**. The problem here is that when I try to print the value **uri** received in **inserirBean.onSelectedCheckBox(uri)**, I don't get the any output, as if it is empty. Below there's the rest of the code:

**InsereDocumento.xhtml**

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{inserirBean.spotlightPtBindings}" var="spotlightbinding">

        <rich:column>
                 <f:facet name="header">*</f:facet>
                 <ui:param name="uri" value="#{spotlightbinding['URI']}"/>

                 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{selectionBean.selected}" />

                    <c:if test="#{selectionBean.selected}">
                        #{inserirBean.onSelectedCheckBox(uri)}"
                    </c:if>

             </rich:column> 

        <c:forEach items="#{inserirBean.variableNamesPt}" var="vname">
             <rich:column>
                 <f:facet name="header">#{vname}</f:facet>
                  #{spotlightbinding[vname]}
             </rich:column> 
         </c:forEach>  


     </rich:dataTable> <br />
```

**SelectionBean**

```
package managedBeans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class CheckBoxSelectionBean implements Serializable {
    private transient boolean selected = false;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CheckBoxSelectionBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

     public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

}
```

**InserirBean** - I'm not showing here how the `List<Map<String, String>>` named **spotlightPtBinding** and how the `List<String>` **variableNamesPt** were populated, because it was a complex process, but I can tell you they are certainly populated, cause I can see their content on the screen.

```
@ManagedBean
public class InsereDocumentoBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private List<String> variableNamesPt = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<Map<String, String>> spotlightPtBindings = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();


         public List<String> getVariableNamesPt() {
        return variableNamesPt;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getSpotlightPtBindings() {
        return this.spotlightPtBindings;
    }

          public void onSelectedCheckBox(String uri) {
        System.out.println("URI: " + uri);
    }
}
```

**What may the problem be? Thank you! I'm new to JSF and need your help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSF rendering is a two-step process: there's *view build time* and *view render time*.
Although they're in the same file, some tags take effect at view build time, some at render time.

JSTL tags like `<c:forEach>`, `<c:if>` and *all tag handlers* (including `<ui:param>`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8400237/785663)) are evaluated at view build time, they add content to the "final" xml tree that is then rendered by JSF.

JSF HTML tags and derivates like `<rich:dataTable>` are evaluated at view render time, so the datatable's `var` is evaluated *later* then the `<ui:param>` which causes `spotlightbinding` not to be bound when it's assigned to `uri`.

Instead, I suggest you assign an ajax listener to call the function:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{selectionBean.selected}">
    <f:ajax listener="#{inserirBean.onSelectedCheckBox(spotlightbinding['URI'])}" />
</h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Note that the listener is called whenever the value *changes*.

Comment: Solved! Perfect! It was a huge help! Thank you so much! :))