# JSF EL nested ternary operator

Tags: jsf, el, facelets, ternary-operator

I have JSF 2.2, PrimeFaces 5.0 web application.

On my page I need to conditionally set `<ui:param/>`. The problem is that a standard ternary operator isn't enough, because I have more than 2 options to choose. This single page serves as an edit and create page for 2 types of users: regular user and a physician.

Here is what I tried:

```
<ui:param name="edit_title"
    value="#{empty dto.id  ? 
(bean.isPhysician ? msg.physicianNewTitle : msg.userNewTitle) :
(bean.isPhysician ? msg.physicianEditTitle : msg.userEditTitle)}" />
```

The result shows wrong title, when `dto.id` is empty and `bean.isPhysician` is false and I can't find a problem or a better solution. Tried to set it conditionally like it was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400066/conditional-variable-definition-in-jsf), but it doesn't work for some reason.

Does anyone know how to solve this kind of trouble?

Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to move more complex logic into the controller. What is the expected and actual output in your example?

Comment: Output is ok except when I try to create a new user - it displays New Physician instead of New User.

Comment: Your logic looks correct. I would break it down into several statements for debugging, making sure the inputs are what you are expecting.

Comment: Try ? #{((empty dto.id)  ? 
(bean.isPhysician ? msg.physicianNewTitle : msg.userNewTitle) :
(bean.isPhysician ? msg.physicianEditTitle : msg.userEditTitle))} : sorry I cant help

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, guys, I have found what was causing the wrong behavior and it has nothing to do with nested ternary operator. It was just wrong calculation of isPhysician variable.

So, if you need to choose from more than 2 conditions in a view - try making it like this:

```
<ui:param name="edit_title"
    value="#{empty dto.id  ? 
(bean.isPhysician ? msg.physicianNewTitle : msg.userNewTitle) :
(bean.isPhysician ? msg.physicianEditTitle : msg.userEditTitle)}" />
```

Or simply move your logic to a bean.
Hope this helps somebody.

Cheers.